# Dask; using apply to update variable

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, multiprocessing, dask

In pandas you can use the [`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) or [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html) methods in a way that instead up returning an updated view of the DataFrame or Series updates a numpy array passed in with the function. For example:

```
In[1]: df = pd.DataFrame({'x': [1,2,3,4,5]})
In[2]: count = np.array([0])
In[3]: def increment(row, count):
           count[0] += row
In[4]: df.x.map(lambda row: increment(row, count))
Out[4]:
    x
0   None
1   None 
2   None 
3   None
4   None
Name: x, dtype: object
In[5]: count
Out[5]: array([15])
```

I would like to be able to replicate this behavior usins [Dask](http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/index.html), but so far my only luck has been with the `map_partitions` method and a bit of a workaround. Is this an issue with the memory space in which the data resides, as my example only uses the one while Dask will be using multiple memory spaces for parallel processing? Or is there a way to force the pandas or Dask `apply` method to return something that is not shaped like the input DataFrame/Series?

Comment: What is your actual objective?  Are you asking if it is possible to have dask tasks mutate global state?  Are you trying to accomplish a custom aggregation?

Comment: @MRocklin  Absolutely a custom aggregation. I can add a minimal example if necessary, but thought this might be a better entry question. Basically I have a very large csv. That csv has a column that contains different length arrays. I need to read each array and lookup another array for each element. This final array is then used to update a count array that has about 2000 elements in it. Like I said I can get it working with map_partitions, but would really like to know if we could get apply working, for future reference.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking depending on tasks that mutate global state is not supported within Dask.

If your goal is a custom aggregation then the [`.reduction`](http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/dataframe-api.html#dask.dataframe.DataFrame.reduction) method may be of use.  This works well if you can write your reduction as a function applied to each partition and then subsequent combination operations.

If your goal is more custom than this then I recommend switching to [dask.delayed](http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/delayed.html) (see also [these docs](http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/delayed-collections.html)).